# UTF-8 Character in filename, the url to the link returns a 404 error

Tags: php, character-encoding

I'm using Fork CMS and when uploading a file with special characters in the filename (e.g. é or à) the filename (présentation.pdf) is saved on the FTP as pr%c3%a9sentation.pdf.

When you link to the file using the back-end the URL is displayed as http://www.domain.com/files/pr%c3%a9sentation.pdf but almost all browsers link you to http://www.domain.com/files/présentation.pdf which results in a http 404 error.

Any suggestions on where I should be looking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to access it like this : http://www.domaine.com/files/pr%25c3%25a9sentation.pdf

But you should remove accentued caracters from filenames before saving them, this will avoid you any issue.

Comment: @MicahHenning Then what is the question? If the file has a "%" in the name, urlencoded you must do %25 to reproduce the same % character. So `pre%25c3%25a9sentation.pdf` will translate into `pr%c3%a9sentation.pdf` which is the name of the file.

Comment: @AlexBelanger Oops. I thought the files were being uploaded via FTP, not HTTP. It seems the word "FTP" is being used to mean a storage space on the server.

Comment: @MicahHenning: Fyi, FTP is File Transfer Protocol, that's how you send or download your file directly on the server. HTTP is HyperText Transfer Protocol, that's when the file is executed and the result is sent back to the user to be viewed. But this have nothing to do with the actual problem and solution posted, really.

Comment: @AlexBelanger Yes, that's why using the term "FTP" in this case is confusing, since the files are actually being transferred via HTTP.

Comment: @MicahHenning Yeah you could simply say its on the server, FTP and HTTP are just one of many ways to access files. Accept an answer whenever you can, here I'm helping you for fun, but some people actually would die for the points.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure both your FTP server and FTP client abide by RFC 2640 so they use UTF-8 encoding instead of ASCII.  ASCII does not support non-English characters, including those with accent marks.  See here for more details:  http://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Character_Set

---

**UPDATE**

I'm guessing by "FTP" you mean a storage space on the server, not that files are being uploaded via the File Transfer Protocol.  If the files are being uploaded via Fork CMS and the filename of the uploaded file becomes pr%c3%a9sentation.pdf, Fork CMS is not properly handling the filename.

Answer (score 1):

The last answer is true.
But if you want to force it, replace the first % with %25c3% and remove the second one.

Answer (score 1):

If the file has a `%` in the name, urlencoded you must do `%25` to reproduce the same `%` character. So `pr%25c3%25a9sentation.pdf` will translate into `pr%c3%a9sentation.pdf` which is the name of the file.

A sane solution would be stripping special characters from file names and respect the Internet File Naming Convention instead of trying to circumvent a problem that shouldn't be there in the first place.

Side note: I'm french so don't tell me `presentation` isn't as readable as `présentation`.

Answer (score 1):

This problem has been solved in the latest Fork CMS releases,
by using CommonUri::uri()